# OData also apply $expand in children on self-referencing entity

Tags: odata, odata-v4

I have a self-referencing entity, and I need to $expand=Other on each level.

Expected result:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Other: {...},
    Children: [
        {
            Id: 2,
            Other: {...},
            Children: [...]
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

But I can't figure out how to write the query.

`/odata/Entities/$expand=Children($levels=max),Other` yields

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Other: {...},
    Children: [
        {
            Id: 2,
            Children: [...]
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

The child (Id: 2) is missing Other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
/odata/Entities/$expand=Children($levels=max;$expand=Other),Other
```